# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject vs Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject

Tags: excel, vsto

I need to access the Selected Event of all the listobjects in all the worksheets of my workbook but when I access worksheet.listobject, that object apparently belongs to 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject and so doesn't have any events where as the table list object belongs to Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject.

And I read that
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject.InnerObject = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject

but i don't know how to use it.

Pls Help

Thanks,
Kavita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you must use Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject.GetVstoObject(lstObj) where lstObj is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject to get the correct object. And it's only available with at Application-level Addin, not at Document-Level, you can read the documentation.
From: [MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10w7dsk2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). And now you have also a [ListObjectExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.extensions.listobjectextensions.aspx)

More info about the events of Tools.Excel.ListObject at: [MSDN Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject_events%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)